# Visual Basic Pythag question - calculate angles of right triangle given lengths

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, math, trigonometry

I'm working on a Pythagorean Theorem program that calculates the sides and angles of a right triangle. I have the side measurements and all that down, but I can't find the Visual Basic function that will allow me to calculate the angles from the side measurements. I've tried asin and sinh, but both give me the wrong measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the functions `Math.Asin()`, `Math.Acos()`, and `Math.Atan()`. These are the inverse trigonometric functions that you can use to find the angles you're after. Sinh is a hyperbolic function and won't be any use for this.

Example:

```
theta = Math.Asin(b/c)
```

where b and c are two sides of your triangle.

Answer (score 0):

They are methods on the Math class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zfefwz9.aspx

It would be Math.Asin(), Math.Sinh()